# Logic for looping back to start of alphabet after last letter in Caesar's Cipher

Tags: c, loops, ascii, cs50, caesar-cipher

I've been writing the below program as an implementation of Caesar's Cipher and it works unless the key provided is larger than 26. The problem is that I don't know how to loop back once the value exceeds 'z' or 'Z'.

What I've tried so far is to nest `if` statements and `while` loops, which caused a memory leak (LOL), so suffice it to say, that I'm pretty stuck.

How to use the program:
`gcc -o caesar caesar.c -lcs50 -lm && ./caesar key(number)` where `caesar.c` is the filename.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool input_valid(int count, string arg);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int key;
    char final_val;
    string string;
    char cipher_string[80];

    if (!input_valid(argc, argv[1]))
    {
        printf("Invalid input!\nUSAGE: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    string = get_string("plaintext: ");
    key = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
    {
        int ascii_val = (int)string[i];

        bool valid_lower_case = (ascii_val + key) >= 'a' && (ascii_val + key) < 'z';
        bool valid_upper_case = (ascii_val + key) >= 'A' && (ascii_val + key) < 'Z';

        if (isalpha(string[i]))
        {
            if (valid_lower_case || valid_upper_case)
            {
                final_val = ascii_val + key;
            }
            else
            {
                // loop back to 'a' if ascii_val reaches 'z'
                final_val = 'a' + (key - ('z' - (ascii_val - 1)));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            final_val = ascii_val;
        }

        cipher_string[i] = final_val;
    }

    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", cipher_string);
}

bool input_valid(int count, string arg)
{
    // input has more args than just the file name
    // input is an integer
    return count > 1 && isdigit(arg[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with the MOD operator, `%`?

It's useful for implementing "ring-oriented" data, e.g.

```
array = [0, 1, 2] // "ring"

array[0 % 3] == 0
array[1 % 3] == 1
array[2 % 3] == 2
array[3 % 3] == 0 // "ring" loops back to 0
array[4 % 3] == 1
array[5 % 3] == 2
```

Mathematically, it's the remainder of division.

```
10 / 4    # (4 * 2) + 2
10 % 4             == 2

17 / 2    # (2 * 8) + 1
17 % 2             == 1
```